# Multiple audio tracks for video playback in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, audio, video

I'm developing a small video editor to make quick edits to a multiple audio track video, using Qt. I'm a bit confused about whether it is possible or not to handle multiple audio tracks in payback and processing in Qt.

###### What I want to do with the video

- list audio tracks
- for each track, manage its volume, and choose to perform channel duplication on a mono track (to make it stereo).
- play the video with the setting I chose for audio tracks, eventually being able to change settings on the fly.
- extract a part of the video with the settings I chose.

I'm not sure if Qt can handle this by itself, or if I need to rely on a library specialized in video processing. Therefore, my question is double

###### If it is possible in Qt-only : how ?

I suppose I need to use `QMediaPlayer` class, but it doesn't look like it can handle multiple tracks at once.

Maybe by splitting the media into several sub-media, but then how to synchronize their playback?

###### Otherwise : external library. Are there any caveats to avoid?

I wonder what is the best way, if there is one, to display video frames (assuming audio will be handled by external lib)?

Should I draw frames directly on a QWidget, or should I use OpenGL directly? Or another method?

**Note: I'm not forcibly looking for a detailed answer, I'm fine with short ones and/or external resources.**

Comment: Audio mixing is fairly trivial, why not just do it yourself?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Why reinventing the wheel if there is already an existing solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching around, I found that it is impossible to do in with Qt as for now.

I found several libraries able to fulfill such purpose (list is non exhaustive for sure) :

- libvlc, which was able to render easily on a QWidget surface, but at the time I looked, was not able to play multiple channels at a time. Next version should be able to do it tho.
- libffmpeg and libav, which are a bit too low-level for what I want, and which I found fairly complicated to use to render on a QWidget surface.
- libopenshot, which has quite a difficult learning curve, and not that much documentation unfortunately, as it is oriented toward nonlinear video editing.
- libgstreamer. The one I chose.

I found libgstreamer to be the best for my purpose, being fairly high level, and well documented. It also is flexible to use, as it allows loading from and dumping to any kind of file automatically.
It is able to render directly on a QWidget surface, which is super convenient.
On the other hand, it has an async and dynamic design which requires a bit more planning and error management, but documentation is there to help.

So far I didn't encountered any major problem so far, I'll update this post if something new comes up.